# Mysterious CSP violation

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, content-security-policy, gopherjs

I am building a chrome extension. When I test it locally, I can take some actions that cause a CSP violation:

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://apis.google.com 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

However, my code does not have any inline javascript! The error console points to the first line of my HTML, namely `<!DOCTYPE html>`, as the culprit:

```
Stack Trace
html/popup.html:1 (anonymous function)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=600, height=600, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script src="../go/go.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 500px; height: 600px">
  <div> ...
```

There are no other `<script>` tags in the document. The `go.js` file is compiled from golang using [gopherjs](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs).

What is going on? How do I figure out what is causing this CSP violation?

Answer (score 0):

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>` this is the cause.
In your `manifest.json`, try adding this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried that change and the error still persisted. Additionally, the error doesn't happen right away -- I have to make some clicks in the app (which are handled by `../go/go.js`) before the CSP violation occurs.